# Deadlock issues when using Service Broker

Tags: sql, sql-server, service-broker

I have a requirement wherein I have to create multiple update and inserts into set of tables.
For this a master stored procedure is being called which inturn will call multiple Stored Procedures
within nested transaction based on a set of data that which is recieved for processing.
Calling the master procedure one by one is slow and that is the reason why we are using Service Broker.
Within the Master Stored procedure it will call a couple of stored procedures which is inserting records to 3 tables and updating 3 others.
All tables involved are indexed. I am using Service Broker for this but am faced with deadlock situations. Each SP call will always work on a unique record always.

The details from the deadlock graph

```
<Column name="TextData" id="1">
<deadlock-list> 
<deadlock victim="process387bab0"> 
<process-list> 
<process id="process387bab0" taskpriority="0" logused="50076" waitresource="KEY: 8:72057599133024256 (53975579c7be)" 
waittime="3458" ownerId="1880362" transactionname="ACTIVATE_ENTITY" lasttranstarted="2012-04-16T12:56:06.713" 
XDES="0x3d5cf590" lockMode="U" schedulerid="1" kpid="7036" status="background" spid="21" sbid="0" ecid="0" 
priority="0" trancount="2"> 
<executionStack> <frame procname="unknown" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"> unknown </frame> 
<frame procname="CMS.dbo.IntOnCaseCreationMessageReceive" line="102" stmtstart="6488" stmtend="6594" 
sqlhandle="0x0300080076459b5a8f92150131a000000100000000000000"> EXECUTE [dbo].MasterSP @MessageBody, 1 </frame> 
</executionStack> <inputbuf> </inputbuf> </process> <process id="process8588388" taskpriority="0" logused="64476" 
waitresource="KEY: 8:72057599261540352 (9fea6888fb07)" waittime="1573" ownerId="1879248" 
transactionname="ACTIVATE_ENTITY" lasttranstarted="2012-04-16T12:56:02.140" XDES="0xc313860" 
lockMode="RangeS-S" schedulerid="1" kpid="7372" status="background" spid="20" sbid="0" ecid="0" 
priority="0" trancount="2"> <executionStack> <frame procname="unknown" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"> unknown </frame> 
<frame procname="CMS.dbo.IndividualSPToBeCalled" line="102" stmtstart="6488" stmtend="6594" 
sqlhandle="0x0300080076459b5a8f92150131a000000100000000000000"> EXECUTE [dbo].IntCreateCases_SB @MessageBody, 1 </frame> </executionStack> 
<inputbuf> </inputbuf> </process> </process-list> <resource-list> <keylock hobtid="72057599133024256" dbid="8" 
objectname="CMS.dbo.TABLE1" indexname="PK_TABLE1" id="lock1e393540" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057599133024256"> <owner-list> 
<owner id="process8588388" mode="X"/> </owner-list> <waiter-list> <waiter id="process387bab0" mode="U" requestType="wait"/> 
</waiter-list> </keylock> <keylock hobtid="72057599261540352" dbid="8" objectname="CMS.dbo.TABLE2" indexname="IX_TABLE2_ON_ID" 
id="lock42febd80" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057599261540352"> <owner-list> <owner id="process387bab0" mode="X"/> </owner-list> 
<waiter-list> <waiter id="process8588388" mode="RangeS-S" requestType="wait"/> </waiter-list> </keylock> </resource-list> </deadlock> 
</deadlock-list> </Column>
```